# Use a modem router as a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, modem

My modem router is Verizon [D-Link DSL-2750B](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C3Q49S8). My apartment already has  an ethernet cable outlet to provide the internet, so I want to use the modem router just as a router without using it as a modem.

I googled a bit to find the solution.

Will the following solution from [How do I convert adsl modem router to normal router?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-adsl-modem-router-to-normal-router/answer/Deepjyoti-Kalita-5?srid=uBwx) work for me?

> if your ADSL modem does not have any WAN port then you can follow the
>   following steps.
>
> - Connect your network cable in any of the LAN port.
> - Connect your computer to another LAN port of the modem.
> - Now check your default gateway of the modem using ipconfig Command in CMD.
> - Now open your browser and put default gateway in the address bar.
> - Give your user ID password.
> - Go to LAN settings and disable DHCP.
> - Restart your computer and its done.

I also have some questions about the solution:

1. I think that step 3 "Now check your default gateway of the modem using ipconfig Command in CMD" is done in Windows, but I am using Ubuntu. What shall I do instead? Which line in the output of which command in Ubuntu gives the default gateway of the modem?
2. In the next to last step, why "Go to LAN settings and disable DHCP"? Does DHCP have any conflict with using the modem router as a router, or as wifi access point?

Thanks.

Comment: Those instructions are wrong. If you follow that you will end up with no IP address and no way to log back in to the router GUI.

Comment: @HackSlash I followed that to diable DHCP, now my login always fails. I reset the device, by sticking a pin into the little hole, but still can't login. what shall I do?

Comment: Read the manual

Answer (score 2):

You are over-complicating things.  Your modem is already configured as a router, therefore you do not have to change a thing.  Simply plug the router into the wall's ethernet jack.  Thats it, you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know  it already configured as a router?

Comment: @Tim because that is its default configuration.

Comment: where do you find it is the default configuration? Also may I ask if it were not, why disabling DHCP?

Comment: Do not disable DHCP. Having an Ethernet outlet still requires all of the functionalities of the DSL-2750B. Reset the router if you do not remember how to undo your changes.